# Code implementing rendering of SVG Markers

Tags: svg, markers

*Where can I get some code to implement rendering of SVG (specifically SVG Markers) in C#?*

I have been using SharpVectorsReloaded. But the code to render SVG Markers is incomplete and buggy. I have been trying to debug and work through the issues but I would love another code source (C# or Java) so that I can get some ideas into what is wrong/missing from the SharpVectorsReloaded implementation. Would you also be able to specifically point to where in the code the SVG Marker rendering is taking place?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Batik's](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/batik/trunk/sources/org/apache/batik/gvt/MarkerShapePainter.java?view=markup) or [Webkit's](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/svg/SVGMarkerElement.cpp?rev=107304) source code can help you? I know Batik is one of the most complete SVG implementations and Webkit is not bad either. The [source of the Canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/source/browse/trunk/canvg.js) library can also help..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this open source https://github.com/vvvv/SVG, it has the definitions you're looking for.